# 'command not found' when trying to run bash script

Tags: linux, bash, docker, unix

I am trying to run a bash script from a script called **dev_ro**, here is how it's being called.

```
export SUBNET="$(first_available_docker_network --lock-seconds 7200)"
```

I am calling dev_ro by ./dev_ro

I am confirm I have

```
#!/bin/bash
```

at the top of both files.

Here are perms for both files

```
 $ ls -lh dev_ro 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ME ME 423 Aug 21 15:57 dev_ro

$ ls -lh first_available_docker_network
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ME ME 2.2K Aug 21 15:55 first_available_docker_network
```

This is the output from running ./dev_ro

```
++ first_available_docker_network --lock-seconds 7200
compose/everest-compose: line 25: first_available_docker_network: command not found
```

Additionally when I try to run the script:

```
ME@SERVER:~/Rosetta/compose$ first_available_docker_network
first_available_docker_network: command not found
ME@SERVER:~/Rosetta/compose$
```

I have the same setup running on a different server and it's working. The code was pulled from Git, so it's the same codebase.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
ME@OTHER_SERVER:~/Rosetta/compose$ first_available_docker_network
DEBUG:root:Docker subnets: [IPv4Network(... etc
ME@OTHER_SERVER:~/Rosetta/compose$ ^C
```

Comment: Add full path to `first_available_docker_network` or use `./first_available_docker_network` if it is in current directory or check your `PATH` variable.

Comment: Found out what it was - I had some env vars injected by salt.

Answer (score 1):

`first_available_docker_network` is not a standard linux command. This must be your custom script. Try executing using its absolute path. For example, instead of using+

> **ME@SERVER:~/Rosetta/compose$** first_available_docker_network

use

> **ME@SERVER:~/Rosetta/compose$** *absolute_path_of_script*/first_available_docker_network

Or alternatively,

You can try adding the path of `first_available_docker_network` to the `PATH` variable.